Expo Router menu and headerLeft missing
Hello everyone first time using expo router.
I'm trying to create a profile menu with other options inside it. On my header I have my initials which are pressable. When I'm pressing them I'm opening this stack screen as modal
<Stack.Screen
        name="(main)/(modals)/menu"
        options={{
          presentation: "transparentModal",
          animation: "slide_from_left",
          title: "",
          headerTransparent: true,
          headerLeft: () => (
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={router.back}>
              <Ionicons name="close-outline" size={34} color={"#fff"} />
            </TouchableOpacity>
          ),
        }}
      />

Here is the screen Im opening

I have two questions. When Im pressing to personal info I want to open an other stack screen with other options. Also I will have other options too.
What I did for this is
  <Link href="(main)/(settings)/personal-information">
        <Paragraph>Personal Info</Paragraph>
      </Link>

Is this the best way? Inside personal-information should I have an other stack screen?
2nd Question is when I'm opening personal information and going back. My headeLeft of menu is gone.
